# change the color of Link in cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to change clolor of link in my cshtml page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("WareHouse", "WareHouseIndex", "Admin")
```

I want to make color of this above link to white. Please suggest what should i do for that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the htmlattributes argument to the call, setting the style:

```
@Html.ActionLink("WareHouse", "WareHouseIndex", "Admin", null, new {style = "color:white"})
```

Comment: Another Approach.         Html.ActionLink("My Link", "MyAction", null, new { @class = "my-class" }) . Then create a CSS a.my-class { color: #333333 }
a.my-class:active { color: #fffffff}
a.my-class:link { color: #3333 }
a.my-class:visited { color: #CCCCCC }

Comment: Weird thing, your anser does work. But if I want to do it better (making a class and add it in a CSS file) then it doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: It might be that the class is working but some other style is overriding the color. You can check in Chrome's developer tools whether a style has been applied and then overwritten by another. You can also try to force it by putting !important in the css class.

Answer (score 2):

use: `@Html.ActionLink("WareHouse", "WareHouseIndex", "Admin", null, new { style = "color: #fff" })`

or better yet `new { @class = "white-link" }` and style with css.